# How to delete Rows which don't start with number zero?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I got a messed up Excel file.
In column A should be only unique entries starting with the number 0Ax..... .
However, there are some random words in the column which don't belong there.
How can I efficiently delete all rows in which the values of column A don't start with 0Ax and so on?

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Create a new column with a formula like `=LEFT(A1,3)="0Ax"`. Sort the whole list accoding to the results of said new column. Delete the rows that you don't need. If you need to maintain the previous order, create also another column with values increasing with rows and use it to resort the list back to its original order.

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Rows Using `AutoFilter`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub deleteRows()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0Ax*"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1)
            On Error Resume Next
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        .Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```